# Get All Order Collection filter by Customizable Options products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Get All Order Collection: A order which has at least one Customizable Options product

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script to get order which have product with custom option.

**Note:** don't use Object Manager, in script for testing you can use and in actual code replace with dependency.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$orderRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
$searchCriteria = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder')->create();
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');


$orders = $orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

foreach($orders as $order){
    $order = $orderRepository->get($order->getId());
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product = $productRepository->get($item->getSku());
        if($product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($product)){
            echo $order->getId();
        }
        
    }
}
```